# Assembly (MIPS) proper use: Registers vs. Stack

Tags: assembly, stack, mips, cpu-registers

When writing MIPS programs, I've heard that its generally good practice to keep the registers clean i.e. to clear the values of the registers to 0 at the end of the program. So my first question is how/why is this necessary/good practice?

Secondly,
If we have a function call with parameters(p1, p2) stored in $4 and $5; at the end of our function definition, is it necessary to clear the values at $4 and $5 or better to leave them as they were at the beginning of the function call?

I've also seen examples of pushing parameters to the stack like this:

```
addi $29, $29, -8
sw $4, 0($29)
sw $5, 4($29)
; At the end of our program:
addi $29, $29, 8
```

When and why is this necessary/good practice?

Finally,
If we are to use some **constants** in our program, say 4 and 1, is it better to keep them on the registers or the stack? For Example:

```
lis $8
.word 4
lis $9
.word 1
```

And then we might use those values in some way for our program and clear them to 0 afterwards.

Or we could choose to store them on the stack by moving the stack pointer back and forth. Which is a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [you usually want to use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Compiler_register_usage) `$zero` instead of `$0`, `$v0–$v1` instead of `$2–$3`, etc... they're easier to understand (and memorize) than plain numbers and assemblers also understand this notation so there's no problem on this side. Also this abstracts your code from the number, so if ever the standard changes (e.g. $zero is no more $0 but $256), your code will still be assembled correctly.

In every CPU architecture there are some conventions on how to use the registers for doing calls and how to behave with the registers within functions. This is called the *calling convention*. You can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS) a brief description for the MIPS calling convention.

> I've heard that its generally good practice to keep the registers
>   clean i.e. to clear the values of the registers to 0 at the end of the
>   program. So my first question is how/why is this necessary/good
>   practice?

I've personally never heard of this practice, but I don't quite agree with it. A better practice would be to restore the previous values before the start of the program.

> Secondly, If we have a function call with parameters(p1, p2) stored in
>   $4 and $5; at the end of our function definition, is it necessary to
>   clear the values at $4 and $5 or better to leave them as they were at
>   the beginning of the function call?

You should leave them as they were at the beginning of the function call. For the caller, it makes no sense you modify this registers.

*Space on the stack is reserved for $a0-$a3 in case the callee needs to save its arguments, but the registers are not stored there by the caller.*

> I've also seen examples of pushing parameters to the stack like this.
>   When and why is this necessary/good practice?

The stack if by definition a temporary storage. If you want to backup register values (e.g. you want to use $aX or $sX), you put them there. Same than before:

*Space on the stack is reserved for $a0-$a3 in case the callee needs to save its arguments*

```
addi $sp, $sp, -8
```

Moves stack pointer register (by convention it's $29). This reserves 8 bytes in the stack.

```
sw $a0, 0($sp)
sw $a1, 4($sp)
```

Saves $a0 to the top of the stack and $a1 as second in stack (keep in mind that stack grows towards lower adresses). This fills the reserved space (8 bytes). This is called the *function entry protocol*.

```
; At the end of our program:
; You forgot, and it's important:
lw $a0, 0($sp)
lw $a1, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
```

You restore saved registers and put stack pointer back to original value. Then the caller will have its stack and parameters untouched. And this is called the *function exit protocol*.

> If we are to use some constants in our program, say 4 and 1, is it
>   better to keep them on the registers or the stack?

Neither. Constants should be used as immediate operands:

```
li $t0, C   ; Load 16-bit constant into $t0
lui $t0, C  ; Load upper 16-bit half-word of $t0
```

Comment: Thanks! Before, I might have misunderstood the concept of 'keeping the registers unchanged', because most of them were 0 to begin with I thought the idea was to clear them to 0 after our program. But I see now that rather the idea is to change them back to their original values if we use them.

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment yet so I am "answering" a comment.

Within the convention mentioned in the answer above, there are some registers that must be saved the stack - the $s0-$s7 registers are "supposed" to be saved when used in procedures.  This means saving the values to the stack, if you find yourself needing to use them. This often happens when output ($v0, $v1) and input ($a0-$a3) registers are not enough to fulfill the purpose of your procedure.

The $ra (return address register) should also be saved to stack when using procedures, and **needs** to be saved if you are using a procedure which calls another procedure or your code will break.

If you need to use temporary registers in the procedure, $t0-$t7 can be used without preserving their values, as their name (temporary) suggests. This is often useful in the case of loop counters or other non-preserved values.

Comment: `$t0..$t9` are your go-to call-clobbered scratch registers when a0..3 and v0..1 aren't enough.